# Two Gaussian priors used as a mean to another gaussian, how to calculate the joint posterior of the two priors

Tags: normal-distribution, prior, posterior, joint-distribution

I have the following distributions:

$$m_1 \sim p(m_1) = \mathcal{N}(m_1 ; 0, 1)$$
$$m_2 \sim p(m_2) = \mathcal{N}(m_2 ; 0, 1)$$
$$x | m_1,m_2 \sim p(x|m_1,m_2) = \mathcal{N}(x ; m_1 + m_2, 1)$$

And I need to find $p(m_1,m_2 | x)$.

What I started doing was calculating $log \: p(m_1)$, $log \: p(m_2)$ and $log \: p(x | m_1, m_2)$, and then using Bayes' theorem and taking its log such that:

$$log \: p(m_1,m_2 | x) = log \: p(x | m_1, m_2) + log \: p(m_1) + log \: p(m_2) - log \: p(x)$$

Now, the professor once did a similar exercise before, but with a single prior being used as the mean to the gaussian of $x$, and when he did the calculations, he freely added/removed any factors that only depended on $x$, so I'm thinking I can remove $log \: p(x)$ and do:

$$log \: p(m_1,m_2 | x) =^+ log \: p(x | m_1, m_2) + log \: p(m_1) + log \: p(m_2)$$

For the same reason, I also remove the $-\frac{1}{2} log(2\pi)$ terms that appear when I take the log of the normal distributions, and have:

$$log \: p(m_1,m_2 | x) =^+ -\frac{1}{2}(x - (m_1 + m_2))^2 - \frac{m_1^2}{2} - \frac{m_2^2}{2}$$

Now, since I have two variables $m_1$ and $m_2$, I'm expecting my posterior to be a multivariate normal distribution. So, by mathematically manipulating the above equation, I'd have to find something of the form $-\frac{1}{2} (M - \mu')^T(M - \mu')$, where M would be a vector containing my two variables, and $\mu'$ would be a function of my data $x$ (and considering $\Sigma^{-1}$ equal to the identity matrix). However, when I try to do that, the best I can get is something like $-\frac{1}{2}[(M - \mu')^T(M - \mu') + (m_1 + m_2)^2]$, where $M = [m_1, m_2]^T$.

Is this approach actually the right way to go and I'm just making math mistakes somewhere, or is there a simpler way to calculate the posterior distribution in this case?

Comment: Your log posterior can be rewritten as 
$-\frac{1}{2} (2(m_1-x/2)^2 +2(m_2-x/2)^2 + 2(m_1-x/2)(m_2-x/2) +C)$ which is enough to write down the mean [x/2,x/2]  and covariance matrix of the normal distribution.

Comment: Why you want two priors for a single parameter? They won't be identifiable...

Comment: @Tim, that's just how the professor gave us the question, so... But I'm curious now, in a practical application, would it be more advantageous to just turn both parameters into a single one?

Comment: @Berne imagine that $A = B$, then $A/2 + B/2 = A + 0 = B + 0 = 0.1 A + 0.9 B$ etc. you can produce infinite number of equivalent solutions (also for cases where $A \ne B$), neither $A$, nor $B$ won't be unique any way. Basically if both $A$ and $B$ are normal, then their sum will be normal, so in the end you'll end with a single normal prior.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I see. So you'd suggest creating a new random variable S = m1 + m2 and working with that instead? In that case my posterior, when plotted, will be a 2D curve, instead of a 3D surface that would be obtained from using the two variables separately, right?